# Paramiko sftp.open calls from webapp fail after a while

Tags: django, paramiko

I am using paramiko in a django app to move uploaded files to a separate asset server. This all works fine for a while (a couple of hours or so?) but then it starts to produce EOFErrors on sftp.open calls. Here are 2 tracebacks that are generated:

```
storages/backends/sftpstorage.py in _read

        return self.sftp.open(remote_path, 'rb')

paramiko/sftp_client.py in open

        t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)

paramiko/sftp_client.py in _request

        num = self._async_request(type(None), t, *arg)

paramiko/sftp_client.py in _async_request

            self._lock.release()

paramiko/sftp.py in _send_packet

        self._write_all(out)

paramiko/sftp.py in _write_all

                raise EOFError()
```

And:

```
django/db/models/fields/files.py in save

        self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)

django/core/files/storage.py in save

        name = self.get_available_name(name)

django/core/files/storage.py in get_available_name

        while self.exists(name):

generic/storage.py in exists

                    raise

storages/backends/sftpstorage.py in exists

            return False

paramiko/sftp_client.py in stat

        t, msg = self._request(CMD_STAT, path)

paramiko/sftp_client.py in _request

        num = self._async_request(type(None), t, *arg)

paramiko/sftp_client.py in _async_request

            self._lock.release()

paramiko/sftp.py in _send_packet

        self._write_all(out)

paramiko/sftp.py in _write_all

                raise EOFError()
```

So this happens both on replacing the photo, as well as on just saving the item, while the photo stays the same. This is due to the fact that an `exists` call is made.

Furthermore, I use django-imagekit for the image scaling, and django-storages' sftpstorage to store the file on the remote machine.

What is weird is that this works fine for a while, but then stops working. Restarting the mod_wsgi by touching the wsgi file makes it work again. What could be the cause of this? Could it be some ssh session re-using that doesn't work?

Comment: Do an 'lsof' on PID for process and make sure there aren't open file descriptors. You may not be closing up old connections and server running out.

Comment: Hmm, upon further thinking, I am using sftp in two places: in the admin, and in the celeryqueue. It appears that this error only shows from actions in the admin. The queue uses sftp.get and sftp.put, where the admin uses sftp.exists, sftp.open and sftp.save.